# ECS Cluster with Capacity Provider not getting deleted during ROLLBACK

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-ecs

I have a cloudformation template as below.

```
Resources:
  EcsCluster:
    Type: 'AWS::ECS::Cluster'
    Properties:
      ClusterName: !Sub 'EcsCluster-${EnvName}'
      CapacityProviders:
        - !Ref OnDemandCapacityProvider
        - !Ref SpotFleetCapacityProvider
      DefaultCapacityProviderStrategy: 
        - CapacityProvider: !Ref OnDemandCapacityProvider
          Base: 2
          Weight: 0
        - CapacityProvider: !Ref SpotFleetCapacityProvider
          Base: 0
          Weight: 1

  OnDemandCapacityProvider:
    Type: AWS::ECS::CapacityProvider
    Properties:
      AutoScalingGroupProvider:
        AutoScalingGroupArn: !Ref OnDemandEcsInstanceAsg
        ManagedScaling:
          MaximumScalingStepSize: 2
          MinimumScalingStepSize: 1
          Status: ENABLED
          TargetCapacity: 100
        ManagedTerminationProtection: ENABLED

  SpotFleetCapacityProvider:
    Type: AWS::ECS::CapacityProvider
    Properties:
      AutoScalingGroupProvider:
        AutoScalingGroupArn: !Ref SpotEcsInstanceAsg
        ManagedScaling:
          MaximumScalingStepSize: 2
          MinimumScalingStepSize: 1
          Status: ENABLED
          TargetCapacity: 100
        ManagedTerminationProtection: DISABLED

...
```

When the stack creation failed, It's trying to rollback and stack rollback failed with below message.

`The following resource(s) failed to delete: [SpotFleetCapacityProvider, OnDemandCapacityProvider, EcsCluster].`

I checked the CapacityProviders, and I could see below message there,

`The capacity provider cannot be deleted because it is associated with cluster: EcsCluster-test-217. Remove the capacity provider from the cluster and try again.`

As per above message, Capacity providers will not get deleted and I need to remove capacity providers from the cluster before trying to delete them, But how can I write to remove them from the cloudformation template.

Appreciate any clue!!

Thanks

Comment: anyone has any clue on this?